# image is not displaying properly

Tags: c#, wpf

[image]
So using snoop I can see that the properties are as follows

```
Image 1
Height = 160
ActualHeight = 160
Width = 372
ActualWidth = 299.7468...
x = 0
y = 0

image 2
Height = 50
ActualHeight = 26.6891...
Width = 50
ActualWidth = 50 
x = 20
y = 20


Image 2
Height = 50
ActualHeight = 26.6891...
Width = 50
ActualWidth = 50 
x = 60
y = 60
```

So my questions is how do I get the ActualHeight and ActualWidth to always be equal to the Height and Width? Also why does image one not appear to be placed at 0,0 on the canvas?

Comment: Please show the relevant code. Do you use DataBinding or are the images hardcoded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make sure that `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` are equal to `Width` and `Height` (provided that they are actually set), you should set the Image's `Stretch` property to `Fill`:

```
<Image ... Width="50" Height="50" Stretch="Fill"/>
```